# How can I make this request (search whenever the user changes the input) without losing any data from that page? Laravel + Inertia

Tags: php, laravel, svelte, inertiajs

I'm developing an app with Laravel + Inertia + Svelte and I need help with an issue that would be possible with the conventional method (Rest API is much simpler, using axios).

I have a page that basically updates a product
route: “products/{id}”

Within this page I need to edit some registration options, one of them is the tags

I have a table in the database that stores previously used tags and I have a search box to show the tags as soon as the user types

My attempt: I created a route Route::post('/products/searchtags’)...
And in the controller I did the search and asked to return return Inertia::render(Products/Edit,
[‘tags’=>[]]);

When doing this, the url changes, and the product data that was in memory (product_name, price...) is deleted and overwritten with the data from the tag search request

How can I make this request (search whenever the user changes the input) without losing any data from that page?

I use Laravel 10, Inertia 1.0

Comment: Post the code what you have done so far, or at least a basic form/controller code so that we can give advice.

Answer (score 0):

without any code, the only suggestion I can make is to send the product data with your request to `searchtags` and resend it in `Inertia::render(Products/Edit, [‘tags’=>[], ‘product ’=>[...]])`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).